# If in array, add relationship, else delete relationship

Tags: neo4j

My database has nodes for Book.

Let's say the user wants to edit the books they've read, resulting in the new array of all books they've read:

```
booksRead = ["Harry Potter", "Lord of the Rings"]
```

How do I:

> create a relationship if Book in booksRead, delete relationships for books that have not been read

So let's say the user put down that they previously read "Hunger Games" by accident. The "Hunger Games" Book would be detached from the User because it is not in the new array `booksRead`.

I know how to do the first part, but need help with deleting the existing relationships for books that have not been read.

```
MATCH (user:User), (book:Book)
WHERE user.user_id = 1 AND book.title in ["Harry Potter", "Lord of the Rings"]
MERGE (user)-[r:READ]->(book)
RETURN book
```

Side question: Would it be better to do the add and removes 1 by 1 instead of passing in the whole new array to overwrite? I'm used to NoSQL like MongoDB where it's easy to just replace the entire array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect the array to hold the full collection of books read, then it's just a matter of either clearing out all books a user has read first then forming all the new relationships with books from the array, or merging all the books first from the input array, and then removing any that aren't in the array.

Here's the query for the second approach, which continues from your original query.

```
MATCH (user:User), (book:Book)
WHERE user.user_id = 1 AND book.title in ["Harry Potter", "Lord of the Rings"]
MERGE (user)-[:READ]->(book)
WITH user, COLLECT(book) as booksRead
MATCH (user)-[r:READ]->(book:Book)
WHERE book NOT IN booksRead
DELETE r
```

Comment: First time seeing WITH and COLLECT. I need to learn more syntax!